# Ubuntu 16.04 can not be install on unallocated disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, 16.04, windows-8

I am trying to install `Ubuntu 16.04` with `Windows 8.1` in dual boot. So I shrink my `Partition F` to get `34GB` of `unallocated disk` space. In the `Ubuntu` setup process, it detects that my PC has `Windows 8` but it doesn't provide `install alongside` option. So I went through `Something else` but in there, the setup process won't allow to create or do anything to the `unallocated partition`. This is the view of my `Disk Management`.

[image] in windows. So I tried to make a `Simple Volume` but it gives me this error[image]. I know that making the disk in to `dynamic` creates lots of trouble. What should I do dual boot both `Windows 8.1` and `Ubuntu 16.04`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have your Windows 8.1 installed in Legacy Mode and Legacy Mode does not support more than 4 primary partitions.

[More on UEFI vs Legacy](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-UEFI-and-Legacy-Mode-which-we-need-to-choose-while-installing-the-OS)

You already have 4 primary partitions created (namely C, E, F & system reserved). Ubuntu installer can't create a fifth primary partition to install Ubuntu on.

You can do any one of the following.

1 : Delete one of your partition (E or F) - Fairly Easy. You definitely know how to do it.

2 : Reinstall Win8.1 in UEFI (if your machine supports UEFI) - Lengthy but better solution.

3 : Convert existing Win8.1 Legacy installation to UEFI without reinstalling - Very complicated and risk of data loss.

Steps for option 3 are very complex and long. Hence I can not include that in this answer. I have given a link which you can follow.

Link - [Convert existing Win8.1 Legacy installation to UEFI without reinstalling](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14286.converting-windows-bios-installation-to-uefi.aspx)